# Meeting invite from Excel macro - no body, set as appointment

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I'm trying to create a vba macro which generates a meeting invite that uses variable data from a worksheet.

My first problem is that it only opens up as an appointment, but not as a meeting with the invitees listed (however, if i click "Invite Attendees" on the appointment, they are prepopulated).

My second problem is that the required information I want in the body does not display.

Below is the code, can anyone assist?

```
Sub Consolidation_Invite()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim objMyApptItem As Object
    Dim recipients As Range


    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'You can use a fixed range or the visible cells in the selection
    'Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng = Sheets("Calendar Invite").Range("A21:B50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMyApptItem = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
    Set recipients = Worksheets("Calendar Invite").Range("B11")

    On Error Resume Next
    With objMyApptItem
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        .recipients.Add recipients
        .Location = " Phone Call"
        .Subject = Worksheets("Calendar Invite").Range("B13")
        .Start = Worksheets("Calendar Invite").Range("B15")
        .AllDayEvent = "False"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display   'or use .Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It IS a meeting request.  The MeetingItem object cannot be created, it is automatically created when you set the MeetingStatus property of an AppointmentItem object to olMeeting and send it to one or more users.  Recipients will receive them as MeetingItem items.

For your second problem, the AppointmentItem object doesn't support an HTMLBody property; only Body and RTFBody.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm still learning VBA, so before I go and try to work this out, is there a way to basically copy a range from excel and paste it into the email using .Body?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so posting the solution in case others wish to use the same. Basically as you can't use HTMLBody, you can compose in Word. So this will copy and paste in the word editor.

I still can't get it to display the invitees by default... but clicking the "Invite Attendees" button isn't such a bit deal.

```
Sub Consolidation_Invite()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olApt As Object
Dim RCP As Range

Const wdPASTERTF As Long = 1

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(1)
Set RCP = Worksheets("Calendar Invite").Range("B11")

With olApt
    .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    .Start = Worksheets("Calendar Invite").Range("B15")
    .AllDayEvent = "False"
    .recipients.Add RCP
    .Location = "Phone Call (please be at your computer)"
    .Subject = Worksheets("Calendar Invite").Range("B13")
    Sheets("Calendar Invite").Range("A21:B50").Copy
    .Display
    .GetInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPASTERTF
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Good job - that's precisely the approach (hack!) I've had to use in one commercial add-in I built. It's really the only way unless you're a masochist and want to learn RTF commands! FYI you can display the attendees page by automating a Ribbon button click using either the Microsoft Active Accessibility SDK or Redemption.